# Storm pulling in stale dependencies

Tags: apache-storm

We are trying to upgrade from Storm 0.10.0 to 1.0.2 and our project uses [kafka-spout](https://github.com/apache/storm/tree/master/external/storm-kafka)

Between versions, `backtype.storm` package-names were changed to `org.apache.storm` package-names by the storm-community.

As part of our own upgrade, we had to change `storm-kafka`'s version also to 1.0.2

But when I run the topology on storm, I get the error about missing classes from older version:

```
apache-storm-1.0.2/bin/storm \
 jar \
$jarFile \
org.apache.storm.flux.Flux \
$yamlFile \
--remote



+-         Apache Storm        -+
+-  data FLow User eXperience  -+
Version: 1.0.2
Parsing file: topology-config.yaml
333  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - loading YAML from input stream...
335  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - Not performing property substitution.
335  [main] INFO  o.a.s.f.p.FluxParser - Not performing environment variable substitution.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: backtype/storm/spout/MultiScheme
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildObject(FluxBuilder.java:291)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildComponents(FluxBuilder.java:350)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.FluxBuilder.buildTopology(FluxBuilder.java:75)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.Flux.runCli(Flux.java:153)
    at org.apache.storm.flux.Flux.main(Flux.java:98)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: backtype.storm.spout.MultiScheme
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 7 more
```

I am not sure from where `backtype.storm` is creeping into my code-base.

I have looked all over the code-base (and `mvn dependency:tree`) for `0.10.0` and `backtype.storm` but those things from older-version are no place to be found.

I even excluded all `storm-kafka` versions from my child-dependencies and then added an explicit dependency on `storm-kafka` but it did not change a thing.

Maven does not seem to be at fault because I do not see any `0.10*` versions in my `~/.m2/repository`:

```
ls ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/storm/*
~/.m2/repository/org/apache/storm/flux:
1.0.2

~/.m2/repository/org/apache/storm/flux-core:
1.0.2

~/.m2/repository/org/apache/storm/storm:
1.0.2

~/.m2/repository/org/apache/storm/storm-kafka:
1.0.2
```

Clearly storm is doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `topology-config.yaml`, Class is loaded dynamically loaded after picking the class name from the yaml file.

Comment: I have searched for `backtype.storm` in all code and also explicitly in `topology-config.yaml` file. There is no `bactype.storm` anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was because of using shaded jar files as dependencies in our code.
One of the shaded jar file used an older version of the storm-dependency and somehow this was not being shown in the `mvn dependency:tree`

On excluding the storm dependencies from the shaded jar dependency, the above error went away.

TL;DR: I actual exploded the eventual jar file (using `jar -xvf final.jar`) and saw duplicate classes in `backtype/storm` and `org/apache/storm` packages and the classes in `backtype/storm` were getting picked up perhaps because `backtype` comes before `org` lexicographically? (Not sure on this one because I would have expected the package name to take precedence in such cases).